# Prevent accidental change of event name emitted by child component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-test

How can I prevent accidental change of event name emitted by child component?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-update',
    template: '<app-reboot-panel (reboot)="doReboot()"></app-reboot-panel>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    doReboot() {
        console.log('reboot action started');
    }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'app-reboot-panel',
    template: '<div><button (click)="onReboot()">Reboot</button></div>'
})
export class RebootComponent {
    @Output() reboot = new EventEmitter();
    onReboot() {
        console.log('reboot buton clicked');
        this.reboot.emit();
    }
}
```

If one changes name of `ParentComponent.doReboot()` in template or ts then AoT build will detect it and fail.

If one changes the name of emitted event `@Output() reboot` the compiler doesn't detect it.

Is there any built-in mechanism into Angular to check if all events used in `ParentComponent` exist in `RebootComponent`?  If not how can I unit test correct @Output assignment in parent component? I know I can unit test `RebootComponent` but one may change `@Output() reboot` and also fix test for it not touching `ParentComponent`.

Comment: If `RebootComponent` is a simple component used only in `ParentComponent`, just test the two together in one `TestBed`. If not, it's probably better to test this at an E2E level; it's a matter of *integration* between multiple components, unit testing tells you whether they each work individually.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `RebootComponent` is used only once as the child of `ParentComponent`. How can I use them together in one `TestBed`?

Comment: Just add both components to the `declarations` array.

Comment: Why didn't you ask in comments? Please don't cold email people about their SO contributions. As for the title, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles